# Print option not available in Microsoft Edge built in PDF Viewer

Tags: pdf, iframe, printing, microsoft-edge

I'am using the iframe plugin to display a PDF file. I am able to see the PRINT, DOWNLOAD and SAVE buttons on Chrome and Firefox but not on Microsoft Edge.

This issue has been marked as WONTFIX here. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/1903522

Is there any workaround for this?